# GetFullPath behavior in .Net Core 3.1.2 differs from .Net 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

The following code fragment

```cs
var x = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\test:");
```

throws this (expected as the path is invalid) exception when run with .Net 4.6.2

`System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'`

But when I run the same code with .Net Core 3.2.1, the method simply returns the input without throwing an exception. AFAIKT the doc does not state that there should be such a behavior change [MSND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netcore-3.1)

So my questions are:

- Am I missing something in the docs etc.?
- Can somebody else reproduce this behavior?
- Should I probably report this as an issue to the dotnet/runtime repository?

Comment: Interesting, this might actually be a bug, or at least the docs need updating.

Comment: Does seem like a bug (and if it was an intended change, then I reckon putting `<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=true" />` in the `app.config` should revert to the old behaviour - but I tried it, and it doesn't).

Comment: It even works if you do something like: `var x = Path.GetFullPath(@":::::::");` and it will return `::\:::::`. [DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VZBOsa)

Comment: @SᴇM intresting i'm getting `/app/:::::::` from the fiddle

Comment: @PatrickBeynio Correct, in fiddle it's `/app/:::::::`, on my local machine it's `::\:::::`.

Comment: Ok, as it could be reproduced and looks weird to others also, I created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/33477).

Comment: Also that issue is related to .net core in general, not only 3.*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is interesting. I can reproduce it perfectly.

It seems that in .NET Framework, it manages to get the full path successfully, but then [demands the neccessary File I/O code access permissions](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,335). In emulating that, it goes out of its way to check for the colon after the drive separator and [throws an exception](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/permissions/fileiopermission.cs,1108).

On .NET Core, it has a vastly different implementation, but it only does the first bit. It gets the full path. It doesn't deal with code access permissions, because these don't exist in .NET Core and the APIs are just stubs for compatibility purposes. They're somewhat deprecated in Framework already anyway.

However, if we turn to the documentation, there's no differentiation. The [Framework docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netframework-4.8) say that `Path.GetFullPath` can throw a `NotSupportedException` if:

> `path` contains a colon (":") that is not part of a volume identifier (for example, "c:\").

Strangely, the documentation for .NET Core says [the exact same thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netcore-3.1), despite not actually throwing the exception in this scenario.

I'd suggest that at the very least this is a documentation bug, if not a runtime bug.

Comment: You were right. .Net core guys [say](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/33477#issuecomment-597805313) this new behavior is intended, and the documentation is out of date. Lets hope they will update the documentation at some point. Also the inconsistencies regarding APIs like [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Path_GetInvalidPathChars) will stay.